# event not picking up on jQuery generated HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery

I used `jQuery` to add append content to my "`.item-table`" in HTML.

After the code is added, the html rendered the content perfectly with all the correct css style. The problem is that the code I wrote in my .js is not working.

So now there are two buttons: 1)button at HTML initiation, 2)added through jQuery

The `.click` works in case 1) but does not on 2)

Do you need to re-apply the js file? or is there something else that can solve this problem?

---

The click event associated with ".item-delete-button"

```
$('.item-delete-button').click(function(){console.log("test")};
```

The code that was added to html

```
$('.item-table').append(
  '<div class="item-table-row col-xs-12">'+
    '<div class="item-delete col-xs-2">'+
      '<button type="button" class="item-delete-button btn btn-warning col-xs-6">Delete</button>'+
    '</div>'+
  '</div>'
);
```

In HTML at initiation

```
<div class="row item-table">
  <div class="item-table-row col-xs-12">
    <div class="item-delete col-xs-2">
      <button type="button" class="item-delete-button btn btn-warning col-xs-6">Delete</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use event delegation for dynamic html, bind the event to the parent element (using `.on`) that exists on DOM ready:

```
$('.item-table').on("click", ".item-delete-button", function(){ 
    console.log("test")
});
```